# Tensor product of basis and dual basis

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors, kronecker-delta, tensor-decomposition

In my textbook is stated the following expression:
$$\hat{\delta}=\delta^i_j(\vec{a}_i\otimes\vec{a}^j)=\vec{a}_i\otimes\vec{a}^i$$
And I just can't understand what the logic here is. First of all which coordinate system are we using because this tensor product is gonna have different components depending on our basis vectors. Does it play a role somewhere that the dot product between the two is equal to one? I'm just so confused here.

Comment: This looks like [Einstein notation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Einstein_notation) where matching upper and lower indices are assumed to be summed over that index.

Comment: ... and the [Kronecker delta](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kronecker_delta) that indicates when indices match.

Comment: yes it is einstein notation

Comment: You can check that this tensor remains unchanged under a change of basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kronecker delta symbol indicates when the indices match:
$$
\delta^i_j 
= \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } i = j, \\ 
0 & \text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$

Thus, for each pair of indices $(i, j)$,
$$
\delta^i_j (\vec{a}_i \otimes \vec{a}^j)
= \begin{cases}
\vec{a}_i \otimes \vec{a}^i & \text{if } i = j, \\ 
0 & \text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$

For instance, in $3$-dimensions, we have $3 \times 3 = 9$ pure tensors
$$
\bigl\{ \vec{a}_i^j \bigr\}
= \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} 
\vec{a}_1 \otimes \vec{a}^1 & 
\vec{a}_1 \otimes \vec{a}^2 & 
\vec{a}_1 \otimes \vec{a}^3 \\ 
\vec{a}_2 \otimes \vec{a}^1 & 
\vec{a}_2 \otimes \vec{a}^2 & 
\vec{a}_2 \otimes \vec{a}^3 \\ 
\vec{a}_3 \otimes \vec{a}^1 & 
\vec{a}_3 \otimes \vec{a}^2 & 
\vec{a}_3 \otimes \vec{a}^3 
\end{array} \right\}, 
$$
but only $3$ survive (nonzero) after pairing with $\delta_j^i$:
$$
\begin{align} 
\delta_j^i\vec{a}_i^j 
&= 
\delta_1^1(\vec{a}_1 \otimes \vec{a}^1) 
+ \delta_2^1(\vec{a}_1 \otimes \vec{a}^2)  
+ \delta_3^1(\vec{a}_1 \otimes \vec{a}^3) \\ 
&\quad{}+ \delta_1^2(\vec{a}_2 \otimes \vec{a}^1) 
+ \delta_2^2(\vec{a}_2 \otimes \vec{a}^2) 
+ \delta_3^2(\vec{a}_2 \otimes \vec{a}^3) \\ 
&\qquad{}+ \delta_1^3(\vec{a}_3 \otimes \vec{a}^1) 
{}+ \delta_2^3(\vec{a}_3 \otimes \vec{a}^2) 
{}+ \delta_3^3(\vec{a}_3 \otimes \vec{a}^3) \\[4pt]
&= \vec{a}_1 \otimes \vec{a}^1 
+ \vec{a}_2 \otimes \vec{a}^2 
+ \vec{a}_3 \otimes \vec{a}^3 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: 1 - Aren't we summing: $\vec{a}_1\otimes\vec{a}^1+\vec{a}_2\otimes\vec{a}^2+\vec{a}_3\otimes\vec{a}^3$ ? 
2- How do we have the confidence to say that exactly this expression is the identity tensor?

Comment: Sorry, those are meant to be sets of the individual terms. I just arranged them in rows and columns to make the indices easier to read. But, yes, **sum.** I will edit.

Comment: And also what drives us to define the identity tensor like $\hat{\delta}=\vec{a}_i\otimes\vec{a}^i$ rather than for example $\hat{\delta}=\vec{a}_i\otimes\vec{a}_i$?

Comment: With one upper and one lower index, this is invariant under change of basis. The change in one cancels the inverse change in the other. This would not work out with two covariant or two contravariant tensors.